# How can I get rails to not precompile assets in vendor directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

asset:precompiling is taking forever on my app. I pretty much never send assets in the vendor directory directly to user and so I don't need those to be precompiled. They are always included by another file in the app/assets directory.

How can I get the precompiler to ignore assets in vendor/assets?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure that the `config.assets.precompile` statement in your application.rb is only referencing the specific files that you want to precompile.  If an asset (js or css) isn't listed in this statement, it won't be precompiled by `rake assets:precompile`.  For example:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['public/public.js', 'public/public.css', 'admin/admin.js', 'admin/admin.css']
```